# Is there a better way to write this function? It already works but I fear it is not efficient

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
function sameAlignment (a, b) {
if (a.alignment > 50 && b.alignment > 50) {
    return true;
} else if (a.alignment < 50 && b.alignment < 50) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

function bondStaff () {
for ( var i = 0; i < army.officers.generals.length; i++ ) { //for each general
    var general = army.officers.generals[i]; 
    for ( var d = 0; d < army.officers.generals.length; d++ ) { //loop through each general
        var general_b = army.officers.generals[d]; 
        if (sameAlignment(general, general_b) && (general.id != general_b.id)) { //if same alignment and not self
            var had_bond = false;
            for (var n = 0; n < general.bonds.length; n++) {
                var bond = general.bonds[n];
                if (bond[0] === general_b.id) {
                    bond[1]++; //if they were already bonded, strengthen the bond
                    had_bond = true;
                }
            };
            if (!had_bond) {
                var new_bond = [general_b.id, 0];
                general.bonds.push(new_bond); //if not create new bond
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have this JSON data structure in which the object officers has an array called generals which contains general objects. The general object has the `alignment` property which is an integer from 1 to 100. The general object also has the `bonds` property which is an array of objects with two properties: officer id and bond strength.

I have some sort of game loops which basically ticks every 500ms and for every general there is I want to check if there is another general with a similar alignment, and in that case if there is no bond existant I want to add a bond to officers.general.bonds and if there already is a bond I want to strengthen it.

How could I optimize this code? It already works.

Comment: Have you proven that the code is too slow by timing it, or running a profiler on it?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I am just learning to write native JS and I wanted to make sure I am on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `sameAlignment` could be written as -

```
function sameAlignment (a, b) {
  return ( (a.alignment > 50 && b.alignment > 50) ||
           (a.alignment < 50 && b.alignment < 50) );
}
```

Also,

```
for ( var i = 0; i < army.officers.generals.length; i++ )
```

Should probably be

```
for ( var i = 0; i < army.officers.generals.length - 1; i++ )
```

And, I think

```
for ( var d = 0; d < army.officers.generals.length; d++ )
```

Should probably be

```
for ( var d = i + 1; d < army.officers.generals.length; d++ )
```